# Which control is available in silverlight to display the image

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is there any control which can be used to display the image on the form in Silverlight 4.
if yes how can i use the control and if not what can i do to show a image on my form.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image Source="/path"></Image>
```